# Can vim recognize indentation styles (tabs vs. spaces) automatically?

Tags: vim, editor, whitespace

I'm working on a large codebase, where each file has different indentation conventions: tabs, 4 spaces, 3 spaces, etc.

I currently default on tabs and do `set shiftwidth=N expandtab smarttab` when I come across a spaces-indented file, but that's annoying.

Is there any functionality in Vim, or a plugin, which can recognize that, for instance, the current buffer uses an indentation with three spaces per shift?

Comment: Crosslink: same question on  different sites [indentation - How do I make Vim adapt to the current indenting style of the file I'm editing? - Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/52/) ■ [whitespace - In Vim, how can I automatically determine whether to use spaces or tabs for indentation? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63196/in-vim-how-c) ■ [editor - Can vim recognize indentation styles (tabs vs. spaces) automatically? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609233)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Various plugins exist that attempt to handle that situation.  Here are a few I found by search for `detect indent` at vim.org

- [sleuth](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4375)
- [DetectIndent](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1171)
- [yafia](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3096)
- [IndentConsistencyCop](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1690)
- [IndentFinder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=513)

Comment: sleuth seems to work better than DetectIndent, in my five minutes of testing. For whatever reason, DetectIndent makes incorrect guesses on even a simple, consistently formatted C file (it has size 2 tabs and DetectIndent thinks it's size 4).

Comment: Although sleuth will set hard tab to `tabstop=8` by default. There's the option of (short of modifying sleuth source code on the line `let tabstop = get(a:detected.options, 'tabstop', get(a:detected.defaults, 'tabstop', [4]))[0]`) setting e.g. `let g:sleuth_vim_defaults = {"tabstop": 4}` (where `&ft='vim'`) but as far as I can see that configuration option is undocumented (I figured out looking at `s:UserOptions()` function in the script) && it's local by filetype.

Answer (score 2):

Good question，I'm facing the same problem too， and recently I wrote such a vim plugin for myself：https://github.com/luochen1990/indent-detector.vim

it has the following features:

> - detect mixed indent and echo warnning on bufEnter and bufWrite
>     automatically.
> - switch setting about indenting to fit the current indenting style automatically.
> - detecting time is limited, so you don't
>     need to worry about opening huge files.

I think it is well designed, and need to be known, post an issue on github if you have any suggestion :)