# How to automatically determine tab type in vim and set expandtab accordingly?

Tags: tabs, vim, vi

Can vim attempt to automatically determine the tab type (tabs or spaces) of a file and set the tab properties to match automatically? If not, is there a plugin that will do this?

I'm working with a large, disorganized code base and it would be nice to have vim attempt to do this with each file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can vim recognize indentation styles (tabs vs. spaces) automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609233/can-vim-recognize-indentation-styles-tabs-vs-spaces-automatically)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this plugin http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1171 is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I have written the [IndentConsistencyCop plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1690) for this detection (and to alert me to files with a mix of styles). It provides an `:IndentConsistencyCop` command; the check can be done automatically when a buffer is opened via the [IndentConsistencyCopAutoCmds extension](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1691).

The plugin page also has links to alternatives.

Comment: Your plugins looks great! I'll try them :). I've noticed that description on IndentConsistencyCop contains duplicated content below "INSTALLATION" section. Do you maintain it in github or any other page?

Comment: @mMontu: Thanks; I've fixed the duplication, that was just an upload issue on vim.org. My plugins aren't on GitHub (yet), but there's a GitHub mirror on http://vim-scripts.org/ for those who want to consume it via a package manager.